# Relation between the eigenvalues of $T^*T$ and the norms of $Tv$ and $v$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let T be a linear transformation in a finite dimensional complex inner product space. I proved that $T^*T$ is self-adjoint and has only real non-negative eigenvalues. Now, I want to show that if we let $\lambda_{min}$ and $\lambda_{max}$ be the minimum and maximum of those eigenvalues, then for a v from that space:

$\lambda_{min}^{1/2} ||v|| \leq ||Tv|| \leq \lambda_{max}^{1/2} ||v|| $

I noticed it is sufficient to show that

$<\lambda_{min} v, v> \leq <T^*Tv, v> \leq <\lambda_{max}v, v> $

But I am stuck. Can someone helo me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T^*T$ is self adjoint, so there is an orthonormal basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T^*T$. From this your result follows by writing $\lVert Tv \rVert^2$ in terms of this basis.